# Detectar se link é do domínio atual ou externo com PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

Atualmente estou usando essa expressão com `preg_replace` para detectar links em um conteúdo enviado via `POST`:

```
$conteudo = $_POST["conteudo"];

$conteudo = preg_replace('!(\s|^)((https?://|www\.)+[a-z0-9_./?=&-]+)!i', ' <a class="link_externo" href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>', $conteudo);

echo $conteudo;
```

Gostaria de saber se o link que é enviado via `POST` é do meu site, ou se é um link externo. Se for do meu site, deverá conter a classe `link_interno`, e, se for externo, então utilizar uma classe `link_externo` e adicionar o `target="_blank"`.

Gostaria também, que a expressão aceite alguns símbolos, pois, se eu enviar um link por exemplo: `www.site.com.br/teste!apenasumteste` ou `www.site.com.br/teste#apenasumteste` ele só vai detectar o link até antes do `!` ou `#`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de obter o domínio atual é pegar o valor da chave `SERVER_NAME` da [*array* `$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php).

> *SERVER_NAME*: O nome *host* do servidor onde o *script* atual é executado. Se o *script*
>   está rodando em um *host* virtual, este será o valor definido para
>   aquele *host* virtual.
>
> **Nota**: `$_SERVER` é um *array* que contem informações como cabeçalhos, *paths*, e localizações do *script*... **Não há** garantia que cada servidor web proverá algum destes; servidores podem omitir alguns, ou fornecer outros [..].

Para extrair as informações de um *link*, por exemplo, o *host*, utilize a [função `parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php), e numa função você verifica se o *host* extraído é equivalente ou não ao teu site:

```php
function verificarLink($link, $dominio) {
  $info = parse_url($link);
  $host = isset($info['host']) ? $info['host'] : "";
  return ((!empty($host) && strcasecmp($host, $dominio) == 0) ? true : false);
}
```

Para realizar a verificação, faça assim:

```php
$link = "http://www.site.com.br/teste!apenasumteste";
$dominio = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if (verificarLink($link, $dominio)) {
    echo "Domínio interno!";
} else {
    echo "Domínio externo!";
}
```

### **Atualização**

Conforme [está resposta do *SOEn*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4390768/1608936), use a expressão regular abaixo para extrair *links* *http*/*https*:

```
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Essa expresão regular pode ser usada na função [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) para extrair todos os *links* de uma *string*:

```
function extrairLinks($conteudo){
    $expressao = "%(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))%";
    preg_match_all($expressao, $conteudo, $resultados);
    $links = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $resultados))[0]; // Remover capturas vazias
    return $links;
}
```

E para utilizá-la faça:

```php
$dominio = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$links = extrairLinks($conteudo);

foreach($links as $link){   
    if (verificarLink($link, $dominio)) {
        echo '<a class="link_interno" href="'. $link .'" target="_blank">'. $link .'</a>' . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo '<a class="link_externo" href="'. $link .'" target="_blank">'. $link .'</a>' . "<br>";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Acontece que, nem sempre o conteúdo enviado será um link. Foi apenas um exemplo simples que dei, o conteúdo poderá variar entre ter ou não links, por isso do `preg_replace`. Então, não posso usar sua resposta...

Comment: podem vir com `http`, `https` ou somente o `www`.

Comment: @Igor Entendi. O conteúdo pode vir com mais de um *link*?

Comment: Sim. @qmechanik

Comment: Não, pois eu preciso que seja com preg_match...

Comment: @Igor Sim, eu tinha atualizado a reposta colocando a função `extrairLinks` que usa o `preg_match_all`, tente fazer um teste e veja se consegue extrair o(s) *link(s)* com essa função.

Comment: @Igor Atualizei novamente, agora o exemplo coloca a classe *interno/externo* dependendo do *link*. Se possível dê o *feedbeck* sobre.